# I have a problem with deleting a node in tree data structures in C

Tags: c

The code in the delete function works for nodes having 1 child and leave nodes, but when I enter 12 (the node has 1 child), that node is still there, is there any problem with the delete function :

```
void Delete(struct Node *current, int data){
     struct Node *X;
     if((current == NULL)
         printf("Can not delete that node since the tree is empty");
     else{
         if(data > current->data)
             Delete(current->rightchild, data);
         else(data < current->data)
             Delete(current->leftchild, data);
         else{
             X = current;
             if(current->leftchild == NULL){
                 current = current->rightchild;
             }
             else(current->rightchild == NULL){
                 current = current->leftchild;
             }
             X = NULL;
          }
}

int main(){
    int tree[7] = {5, 4, 15, 3, 12, 20, 13};
    struct Node *current;
    int I = 0;
    for(; I < 7; ++I){
        Tree(tree[I]); // Tree is the tree-creating function
    }
    current = root;
    printf("Entering the node u want to delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    Delete(current, j);
    InOrder_Traversal(root); // this is the printing function
```

I expect the output 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 15, 20 to be 3, 4, 5, 13, 15, 20, but the node 12 is still there when I enter 12.

Comment: `current = current->rightchild;` The caller won't know about that. `current` is a local variable.

Comment: can u help me fix that, I do not really understand what u mean

Comment: Look up "pass by value vs pass by reference".

Comment: @NguyễnTrọngCương [Do you see the difference](https://pastebin.com/raw/Em8PU9BZ)?